# Using command line to replace text in all files in folder?

Tags: perl, command-line

I need to replace text in all the files in one of my folders and am using Perl but getting an error.

This is what I am running:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/<START>/<url><loc>http://www.mysite.com/page//g' *
```

Basically I just need to replace

```
<START>
```

with this:

```
<url><loc>http://www.mysite.com/page/
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Illegal division by zero at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

Can someone tell me what I should be doing?  I've also tried several other methods but none seem to be working...  I really need it to be done via command line so that it's faster because there are over ten million lines.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape slashes.
`s/<START>/<url><loc>http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/page\//g`

Answer (score 10):

The /es in your replacement text are being virewed as delimeters, and also as the division operator.  You can either escape the slases as \/ where appropriate, or use alternate delimeters.  Try:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's#<START>#<url><loc>http://www.mysite.com/page/#g' *
```